# SQL SELECT with bad data

Tags: sql

If a column has bad data such as:

```
 45612345698
 (456)123-7452
 125-145-9856
```

Without fixing the data. Is it possible to have a sql query of 1251459856 which then would return the 3rd item in the column?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hmmm . . . you could use `replace()`:

```
where replace(replace(replace(col, '-', ''), '(', ''), ')', '') = '1251459856'
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data is worse than just "-",")" and "(" you could go for a more generic solution and strip on any non-numeric character with the following

```
WITH sample_data_tab (str) AS
(
SELECT '45612345698' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '(456)123-7452' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '125-145-9856' FROM DUAL UNION
SELECT '989 145 9856' FROM DUAL 
)
SELECT regexp_replace(str, '[^0-9]', '') FROM sample_data_tab
```